# numpy asmatrix sometimes produces an array of lists

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am using numpy of python to convert multi dimensional data into matrix by using numpy.asmatrix().

```
data_array = [[] for k in range(K)]
while Append data to data_array:
   data_array[k].append(data)
mymatrix = numpy.asmatrix(data_array)
```

The data_array ends up with K*E. While I try to use mymatrix for further manipulation, it turns out some of them works but others still remains as list. When I print it out, it looks like

```
[[ list([..., ...]), list(..., ...) ]]
```

Does anyone knows the potential reason for that?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make a matrix out of at least 3 dimensions. But a matrix is inherently a 2D thing. So the only thing NumPy could give you is a matrix of lists (or of arrays, or of… some kind of sequence to hold the extra dimensions), or an error, so I guess it chose the first one. If you actually want 3 dimensions, you want an array, not a matrix. (In fact, you usually want an array with numpy even if you only want 2 dimensions.)

Comment: Meanwhile, can you turn this into a [mcve]? That pseudocode obviously isn't runnable, but it also doesn't tell us what that `E` is that you're talking about, or what those `data` values are.

Comment: Do those lists vary in size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are doing the equivalent of:

```
In [5]: np.matrix([[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]])
Out[5]: matrix([[list([1, 2, 3]), list([2, 3]), list([3])]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your approach to create the entire 2D array first, then fill it in.  Something like this:

```
mymatrix = np.empty((K, N))
for k in range(K):
    mymatrix[k] = data
```